# Conditional Time based htaccess redirects

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to set redirects based on time but I'm having a difficult time. It is a WP site. Essentially, I will redirect the "page1" to different pages based on time of day on day only. as an example: from 2 to 3pm - redirect to page2, from 3 to 4pm - redirect to page3, etc. For the moment, I'm just trying to get even one to work to test out the process and it's not working. This is the code I'm using for testing:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Following Added by Pardeep

# CONDITIONAL REDIRECTS
# TEST TIME ZONE
#RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /page1
#RewriteCond %{TIME} >=20210304150000
#RewriteCond %{TIME} <20210304160000
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/page2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: For starters, you need to put your own rewriting _above_ the default WP rewriting – otherwise, any request that does not match an existing file or folder, will get rewritten to WP’s index.php, and due to the [L] flag the process ends after that.

Comment: that worked!! thanks for much.